# how do I specify what adapter should my discord bot use using discord.py

Tags: adapter, discord, discord.py

I created a project surrounding the tello drone and a discord bot that allows anyone to command the drone from far away as long as the bot is responding and they're in the server.it works well however i need to create a project file for school and i now realized that i didn't specify the adapter i use (i need for my drone considering i both need internet access and access to the tello) i assume it's because for some reasons it uses the NIC i want it to use, but how do i make sure it will always use a specific adapter so it wont be just by chance.

```
import discord, time, math
from discord.ext import commands
from smartello import smartello
from stream import stream

tello_bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = 'tello: ')
tello = smartello()
streaming = stream()
```

Comment: disclaimer, both smartello and stream are classes i created in other files and this is just a small part of the beginning of the program, i figured the rest isn't important for the question, i also use the function tello_bot.run(<token>) so if the answer is in that function i figured it should be mentioned